# 301 redirection code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have created 301 redirection code for my website. Following is my code to all my categories to redirect to new url

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^testsite.com/categories/city/$1 [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.testsite.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

I want to redirect http://www.testsite.com/categories/city/pune to http://www.testsite.com/Pune

Let me know my code is correct or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not correct. The `%{HTTP_HOST}` is only the host that's provided in the `Host:` header of the request. It's not going to include any path info. You could separate that condition into 2 things:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?categories/city/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I have one more question regarding htaccess I have following url http://www.testsite.com/index.php?dispatch=themes_search.themes_search&flvcity=Pune&flvtype=43  I want to display this url as http://www.mysite.com /Themes/Pune/Chocolates  How can i do this?

Comment: @absolutek that's a totally different problem, you should ask a separate question because I can't read your URLs when you put them in a comment.